# Get Arquillians Code Coverage Using JaCoCo

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, jboss-arquillian, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a Maven build that runs Arquillian tests on a Wildfly. What I want to do is run JaCoCo as well so that I get a test coverage.

What I did to my working Arquillian setup: I changed the parent's *pom.xml* the following way:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>

    <jacoco.out.ut.file>../target/jacoco/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.out.ut.file>
    <jacoco.out.it.file>../target/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.out.it.file>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${jacoco.out.ut.file},${jacoco.out.it.file}</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-ut-agent</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${jacoco.out.ut.file}</destFile>
                        <propertyName>jacoco.agent.ut.arg</propertyName>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-it-agent</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${jacoco.out.it.file}</destFile>
                        <propertyName>jacoco.agent.it.arg</propertyName>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${test.argLine} ${jacoco.agent.it.arg}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${test.argLine} ${jacoco.agent.ut.arg}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

That's a setup that works in multiple other projects (without Arquillian), so I assume it must work now, too.

For the module hosting the integration project I added the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-jacoco</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The `maven-surefire-plugin` is called there (which is weird to me, but I tried `maven-failsafe-plugin` and it didn't work either).

When executed the module produces a *jacoco.exec* (which is 70kb for only the one module, so at least not empty). Sonar uses these files in the report generation. Still the code coverage gets displayed as 0%.

I found a couple tutorials on this topic, but they all seem to be missing a step (at least the setup is always identical to mine).

How do I get Arquillian to use JaCoCo to report the code coverage?

Comment: Did you get any working solution?

Comment: @sauveerpandey No, sorry.

Comment: Please take a look for well configuring pom.xml within a [multi project pom.xml](https://blog.qaware.de/posts/sonarqube-and-jacoco/)